# Select record where id is one of collection id

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

In a spring mvc application i have 3 database tables (including one mapping table) and their 2 corresponding java entities.

The entities are:-

```
public class User {
        private Long id;
        private String userName;

        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)  
        @JoinTable(name = "user_location",  
        joinColumns        = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},  
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "location_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}  
                )  
        private Set<Location> location;
    }

public class Location {
        private Long id;
        private String locationCode;
    }
```

Three tables are users, location and user_location.

I want to select a user whose location id is equal to a particular id.
Since user can have multiple locations i am not sure how to write a hibernate query for this. I tried few combinations below but i am either getting a exception,

```
illegal attempt to dereference collection [{synthetic-alias}{non-qualified-property-ref}] with element property reference [id]
```

or getting a list of User and Location objects. i just want a list of user objects.

- from User where userName = :userName and :locationId in (location.id)
- from User user inner join user.location loc where user.userName = :usersName and loc.id = :locationId

**Update:**
I tried query,

```
Query query = getCurrentSession().createQuery("from User user inner join user.location loc where user.userName = :usersName and loc.id = :locationId");
```

Hibernate generates following plain SQL from above query and returns a list of User and Location objects. For example if there is one location for an user that matches above query hibernate returns a list that contains one User and one Location object.

```
select
        user0_.id as id1_18_0_,
        location2_.id as id1_5_1_,
        user0_.user_name as user_na11_18_0_,
        location2_.location_code as location3_5_1_       
    from
        users user0_ 
    inner join
        user_location location1_ 
            on user0_.id=location1_.user_id 
    inner join
        location location2_ 
            on location1_.location_id=location2_.id 
    where
        user0_.user_name=? 
        and location2_.id=?
```

Comment: What do you mean by list of User and Location objects? Could you add your query to the post?

Comment: Hello Orest, please see my update in response to your comment. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use next criteria:

```
Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(User.class, "u");
criteria.createAlias("location", "loc");
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("u.userName", "userName");
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("loc.id", locationId);

List<User> users = criteria.list();
```

Or you could try HQL typed query:

```
TypedQuery<User> query =
    getCurrentSession().createQuery("SELECT User.* FROM User u JOIN user_location ul ON u.id = ul.user_id JOIN Location l ON ul.location_id = l.id WHERE u.userName = :userName AND l.id = :locationId", User.class)
      .setParameter("userName", "userName")
      .setParameter("locationOd", locationId);

List<User> users = query.getResultList();
```